# Inheriting setUp method Python Unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, inheritance

I have a question regarding unittest with Python! Let's say that I have a docker container set up that handles a specific api endpoint (let's say users, ex: `my_site/users/etc/etc/etc`). There are quite a few different layers that are broken up and handled for this container. Classes that handle the actual call and response, logic layer, data layer. I am wanting to write tests around the specific calls (just checking for status codes).

There are a lot of different classes that act as Handlers for the given endpoints. There are a few things that I would have to set up differently per one, however, each one inherits from Application and uses some methods from it. I am wanting to do a `setUp class` for my unittest so I don't have to re-establish this each time. Any advice will help. So far I've mainly seen that inheritance is a bad idea with testing, however, I am only wanting to use this for setUp. Here's an example:

```
class SetUpClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self._some_data = data_set.FirstOne()
        self._another_data_set = data_set.SecondOne()
    def get_app(self):
        config = Config()
        return Application(config,
            first_one=self._some_data,
            second_one=self._another_data_set)


class TestFirstHandler(SetUpClass, unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        new_var = something 
    def tearDown(self):
         pass
    def test_this_handler(self):
      # This specific handler needs the application to function
      # but I don't want to define it in this test class
      res = self.fetch('some_url/users')
      self.assertEqual(res.code, 200)


class TestSecondHandler(SetUpClass, unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        different_var_thats_specific_to_this_handler = something_else
    def tearDown(self):
         pass
    def test_this_handler(self):
      # This specific handler needs the application to function
      # but I don't want to define it in this test class
      res = self.fetch('some_url/users/account/?something_custom={}'.format('WOW'))
      self.assertEqual(res.code, 200)
```

Thanks again!!

Comment: So your question is "I've heard that inheriting from TestCases is bad, is it really"?

Comment: That is part of the question. The other, is that if it isn't bad, how would one actually inherit from the set up class. I just haven't seen it done.

Comment: I can't really comment on if that's bad, but you already inherited from the baseclass. But you overwrite the `setUp` method each time. If you want to extend the `setUp` function, you should call the super function , i.e. `def setUp(self): SetUpClass.setUp(self)` and after that your code.

Comment: Ahh thanks! That definitely helps

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, you just need to learn how to use [`super()`](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/). You also don't need to repeat `TestCase` in the list of base classes.

Here's the simple version for Python 3:

```
class TestFirstHandler(SetUpClass):
    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        new_var = something
    def tearDown(self):  # Easier to not declare this if it's empty.
        super().tearDown()
    def test_this_handler(self):
      # This specific handler needs the application to function
      # but I don't want to define it in this test class
      res = self.fetch('some_url/users')
      self.assertEqual(res.code, 200)
```

Comment: Looking back at this after a couple years.. Thanks for the example Don! I definitely needed a better understanding of inheritance concepts.